# Wrong date from mysql in order by

Tags: php, mysql, date

Greetings hope to get some help from you here as i been searching high and low for this.

This query works but its not the results i wanted more correctly not the right date format i want it in.

```
SELECT DISTINCT colum FROM table WHERE colum IS NOT NULL
```

This query gives me the dates

```
01.04.13
02.04.13
03.04.13
30.03.13
31.03.13
```

I wanted it to show latest date.

This info is posted in colum that stores the info as text. It is posted in the following format

```
dd.mm.yy
```

I wanted it then to show me the results as in
03.04.13 since this is todays date. i know i can limit it to 1 but still it will show the wrong date.

Thank you again for all help so far

Comment: Dates should be stored using the date data type. Otherwise, what's the point?

Comment: Tried to store it as dates but the result would then be 2031.04.01 or something totaly wrong since the data is posted as dd.mm.yy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
select distinct column from tab where column1 = date_format(curdate(),'%d.%m.%y') AND brukernavn is not null order by brukernavn;
```

Comment: This worked brilliant for me aswell, thank you for a short easy way to say it.

Comment: Would you be able to help me with the same SQL code but how would you add order by brukernavn and IS NOT NULL in that query ?

Comment: @Eventyret please expalin me more what you want .. is `brukernavn` a column in your table .. and you want conditions on it .. ?

Comment: Sorry my late reply.
the code you want works, but i wanted it to be order by another colum wich is brukernavn. (my fault not saying colum) and it is not null.
Thank you again

Answer (score 3):

First, you should not be storing a date as a string, you should store a data as a DateTime datatype.

Since you are storing it as a string, you will have to convert it to a date to get the `max()` date value. The following uses the [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert the string to a date to get the max value:

```
select max(str_to_date(yourdate, '%d.%m.%y')) MaxDate
from table1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49dd3/3)

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to save DATES in date or datetime

2) try MAX() function in MySQL
or try to ORDER BY date DESC and LIMIT 1

3) by the way, did you try using DISTINCT with GROUP BY?